# Explanation of congruence and modulo

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences

Consider the set $A$ = {${-6, -5 -4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}$}

Write down the numbers in $A$ congruent to $1$ modulo $4$.

---

Can someone explain why the answer is not $-4,-1,-4,8,12$  but instead $−3, 1, 5, 9$.

Comment: what numbers can you express as $4k+1$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to verify the definition :
$$a \equiv b \pmod n \iff n | (a-b)$$

---

$$a \equiv 1 \pmod 4 \iff 4 | (a-1)$$

What numbers in the given list are divisible by $4$ after subtracting $1$ ?

Comment: Thanks I understand it better presented like that